# Python incorrectly reading from a txt file

Tags: python, unicode

I am making a script to encrypt a file using a caeser cypher, using random other scripts I made as tests. It writes to a txt document correctly, with the cypher active, but when I try to read from the file, it adds Â€ where there should be a padding character (letter x cyphered by a key of 8, to a unicode index of 128).

The unicode index for where the padding character should be is over 3000 for the euro symbol, and the accented A shouldn't be there in the first place, this is the code I am using to run the cypher:

```
def encrypt(file = str, key = int):
    with open(file) as d:
        data = d.read()
    char = []
    for i in data:
        i = ord(i)+key
        i = chr(i)
        char.append(i)
    file = open("encryptedcode.txt","w", encoding = "utf-8")
    for x in char:
        file.write(x)
encrypt("C:/Users/chris/OneDrive/Homework Files/DT/advstrings.py",8)
```

This is the non-encrypted code in the file advstrings.py:

```
def advstrings():
    word = input("Please enter a word: ")
    print(word[-1])
    x = len(word)-2
    for i in range(0,len(word)-1):
        print(word[x])
        x = x-1
```

This is what shows up in the encrypted file:

```
lmn(il\~{|zqvo{01B((((wzl(E(qvx}|0\*Xtmi{m(mv|mz(i(wzlB(\*1((((xzqv|0wzlc59e1(((((E(tmv0wzl15:((((nwz(q(qv(zivom084tmv0wzl1591B((((((((xzqv|0wzlce1(((((((((E(59
```

Which is correct, however when I read from this file, and then write it to a new file, this shows up:

```
lmn(il\~{|zqvo{01B((((wzl(E(qvx}|0\*Xtmi{m(mv|mz(i(wzlB(\*1((((xzqv|0wzlc59e1((((Â€(E(tmv0wzl15:((((nwz(q(qv(zivom084tmv0wzl1591B((((((((xzqv|0wzlcÂ€e1((((((((Â€(E(Â€59
```

This is what I use to decrypt it:

```
def decrypt():
    newchar = []
    file = open("encryptedcode2.txt","w", encoding = "utf-8")
    with open("C:/Users/chris/OneDrive/Homework Files/DT/encryptedcode.txt") as c:
        chars = c.read()
    for x in chars:
        x = ord(x)-8
        x = chr(x)
        newchar.append(x)
    print(*newchar, sep = "")
decrypt()
```

And finally, this is what it prints in IDLE:

```
def advstrings():
    word = input("Please enter a word: ")
    print(word\[-1\])
    º₤ = len(word)-2
    for i in range(0,len(word)-1):
        print(word\[º₤\])
        º₤ = º₤-1
```

Apologies if this is alot to read, but python doesn't seem to appreciate me using unicode indeces over ASCII's 127

Comment: I'd put the `encoding="utf-8"` in the `with open(file) as d:` line as well

Comment: both your encoding AND your cipher are wrong, will post an answer with proper solution

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on Linux so it might be platform dependent perhaps related to saving the file to OneDrive

Comment: @aw4lly that worked, thanks. I also had to put `encoding="utf-8"` at `with open(file directory) as c` in the decrypt script and then it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to achieve is the extended version, but the actual ceaser cipher only works on alphabetical characters, not numbers and special symbols:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lower, ascii_uppercase as upper

# Intended cipher method (encrypts ONLY ALPHABETICAL characters)
def encrypt(string, key=0):
    buffer = []
    lower_offset = ord('a')-key
    upper_offset = ord('A')-key
    for char in string:
        if char.isalpha():
            if char.islower():
                buffer.append(lower[(ord(char)-lower_offset)%26])
            else:
                buffer.append(upper[(ord(char)-upper_offset)%26])
        else:
            buffer.append(char)
    return ''.join(buffer)

# Extending the algorithm to work with any arbitary alphabet
def encrypt_extended(string, key=0, alphabet=[chr(i) for i in range(128)]):
    return ''.join([alphabet[(ord(char)+key)%len(alphabet)] for char in string])

def read_from(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        return f.read()

def write_to(file_name, content):
    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        f.write(content)

        
write_to('hello.txt', 'Hello world!')
original = read_from('hello.txt')
print("Original message is:")
print(original)
encrypted = encrypt(original, 8)
print("Encrypted message is:")
print(encrypted)
write_to('encrypted.txt', encrypted)
decrypted = encrypt(read_from('encrypted.txt'), -8)
print("Decrypted message is:")
print(decrypted)
print(f"Does the decrypted message match the original? {original==decrypted}")
```